# Is it possible to convert photos created with an uncalibrated monitor to the calibrated profile?

Tags: calibration

I ordered a Colorimeter and I am wondering if it is possible to save my old monitor ICC profile before the calibration so that I can later in Photoshop convert my old images to the new profile so that I will have the colors I originally saw on my uncalibrated monitor

I am a total newbie regarding color management so feel free to educate me on any relevant details regarding this that I may have overlooked

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your colorimeter software options. In general you can profile your current setup before you calibrate the monitor. And many calibration tools allow you to compare the difference.

You can then attach this profile to your old images.

Comment: Cool - can I just take the ICC profile of the monitor I used and attach it to the image or is that faulty thinking? Also what happens if there already is a profile attached to the image? Can I / Do I have to mix them together somehow?

Comment: @TomArrow Yes just use  Assign profile